# read information from a file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to read information from a .txt file and then use it in a ros node.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172933/read-information-from-a-file/) by [nat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18800/nat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not just use the C++ api to read file ?

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>

std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
  std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (in)
  {
    return(std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
  }
  throw(errno);
}
```

Check if your file exist, of course it depends also of the content of the file.
With a data file like that :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

It's works with this piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("test.txt");
  std::vector<int> data;

  int a[3][3];

  std::memset(a, 0, sizeof(a[0][0]) * 3 * 3);

  if(file.is_open())
  {
    for(int i=0;i<3 && file.good() ;i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<3 && file.good() ;j++)
      {
        file >> a[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  else std::cerr<<"File not found !"<<std::endl;

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      std::cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Jérôme](https://answers.ros.org/users/5102/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/) with karma: 36 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18800/nat/) on 2014-06-06**:
thanks .
In fact I have tried with the following code:

ifstream label1("File_name");

for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
{

```
        label1 >> a[i][j];
}
}
```

however, only appear 0 in the array a.